# Confused about Docker 1.12 types

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am new to docker and I am a bit confused of what is the difference between `Tasks`/`Containers` and between `Images`/`Services`. If somebody can explain a little bit about them I will appreciate it.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.docker.com/?
Please ask specific questions, this is too general/broad for SO

Comment: The docs "Get Started" has an [image and container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_two/#/learn-about-images-containers) section.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Image: this is your definition, it contains all the files, environment variables, etc, needed to create a container.
- Container: this is an instance of an image, it includes the network, places a RW layer over RO image data, attaches volumes, etc
- Services: These are how swarm manages a running image, with scale it may be multiple containers, and it includes features like service discovery
- Tasks: They've moved away from this with the GA release and just used `docker service ps`, but a task is a container within a service
- Stack: This is a group of services, defined from the experimental DAB "bundle" files. It will become the `docker-compose` equivalent within Swarm.